# Forward reservation of memory in tree-like structure

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, tree

How to nicely reserve memory of tree-like structure? Let's say that this would be implemented by STL vectors:

```
struct Leaf
{
    int val;
};

struct Branch
{
    std::vector<Leaf> leaves;
};
```

Now, I can reserve some memory for vector of `Branch`es

```
std::vector<Branch> branches;
branches.reserve(10);
```

But how to reserve memory for `leaves` at the same time (not for example during construction of `Branch` objects)?

Comment: You cannot. Only actual vectors can reserve memory. Since `branches` doesn't contain any actual vectors (only *space* for them), there's nobody around who could reserve anything.

Comment: @KerrekSB I just provided some code to express my problem, but my question is not limited to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider storing the whole tree in a single array, possibly a vector. Let's say you have a structure `Node`:

```
struct Node
{
    int val;
    vector<size_t> children;
};

vector<Node> tree;
```

Then the `tree[0]` is the root of the tree. Each time you want to add a new branch in certain node, let's say `tree[i]`, you do:

```
tree.resize(tree.size()+1);
tree[i].children.push_back(tree.size()-1);
// you can also set the value of the new node:
tree.back().val = 123;
```

Then you can traverse the tree easily by starting from any node (including the root) and looking through its children.

Here is an example of traversing the tree using DFS:

```
void dfs(size_t x)
{
    // you can do sth here, for example:
    printf("node: %d, number of children: %d\n", x, tree[x].children.size());

    // go deeper in the tree to the node's children:
    for (size_t i=0; i<tree[x].children.size(); ++i)
        dfs(tree[x].children[i]);
}

// starting DFS from the root:
dfs(0);
```

This way you can reserve memory for the tree:

```
tree.reserve(100);
```

Comment: Please don't use `int` for vector indices. `size_t` is the only right type for that.

Comment: Personally I don't mind, but I've edited the post and replaced `int` with `size_t`.

Comment: `tree.resize(tree.size()+1);` => **NO !!** This completely trumps the exponential growth behavior!

Comment: That's only the case of adding a single element. You can always reserve some amount of memory at the beginning to prevent the exponential growth.

Comment: Idea is decent, however you still need to allocate space for `vector<size_t> children`. It's possible to use children-to-parent relationship if top-down traversing is not required. Then you can replace `vector<size_t> children` with `size_t parent`. But still this will work only if leaves are of the same type as root and branches.

Comment: True, but if the number of any node's children is limited it's no longer a problem. You can often assume a reasonable upper limit for it.

Comment: What's more, if there's a need for a node to have a very big number of children, then it's certain that there won't be many such nodes. Why? Because if almost every node had to hold a large number of children, then you could safely limit it (simply by the available memory). And if only few nodes had to have many children, then they wouldn't have a big impact on the performance or you could just reserve some memory for them.

Answer (score 1):

Make some stack of pointers to pre-initialized empty `Leaf`s before initialize the whole tree (or maybe, as a part of tree). After that, you could just `pop` `Leaf` from stack and attach it to particular `Branch` (and fill up `Leaf`s with desired value...). Of course, then you should change: `std::vector<Leaf>` to `std::vector<Leaf*>`.

When stack will be empty, create another set of empty `Leaf`s.

Comment: This will copy the leaves from the stack onto the vectors in the branches.

Comment: OH, I had on my mind stack of pointers to initialized `Leaf`s of course.

Comment: However, `std::vector<Leaf*>` will still need to allocate space for its elements.

Comment: Not really, expanding vector only for pointer will be much quicker operation than expanding vector by whole new object.

Answer (score 1):

How much memory do you reserve at all when you try to reserve it for the `Branch`es? Each one of them contains a `std::vector` so it's size is variable.

My suggestion would be to actually construct a vector filled with (empty) `Branch`es, but at the same time *reserve* the space for their `Leaf`s, like this:

if you write a memory reserving constructor for the Branch class/struct:

```
struct Branch{
    std::vector <Leaf> leaves;
    Branch (int expectedL = 10){
        leaves.reserve(expectedL);
    }
};
```

then you can do:

```
std::vector<Branch> branches(10);
```

or

```
std::vector<Branch> branches(10, 42);
```

Not exactly what you're asking but maybe it helps.